# Exposing React child component to JavaScript on webpage

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I'm pretty new to rxjs, and trying to understand what's needed here to expose the Chat object in the Bot Framework, as I need to call some methods in it I'll add. I essentially need access to the created Chat component from the webpage, which right now has a BotChat.App. There's also a BotChat.Chat, but that doesn't seem to be the instance I need access to.

The following is used from the Bot Framework by calling BotChat.App({params});
That in turn creates a Chat component (eventually in App.tsx below). I need to basically expose the Chat instance that is used, as I want to modify it.

BotChat.ts (Complete)

```
export { App, AppProps } from './App';
export { Chat, ChatProps } from './Chat';
export * from 'botframework-directlinejs';
export { queryParams } from './Attachment';
export { SpeechOptions } from './SpeechOptions'
export { Speech } from './SpeechModule'
import { FormatOptions } from './Types';
// below are shims for compatibility with old browsers (IE 10 being the main culprit)
import 'core-js/modules/es6.string.starts-with';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.find';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.find-index';
```

And here in App.tsx note the Chat component used below. That is what I need to expose up through the webpage. A bit confused as to if it's exporting a "Chat" type as opposed to getting access to the instance of Chat being used in App.tsx. Hope this makes some sense :)

App.tsx (Complete)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Chat, ChatProps } from './Chat';
import * as konsole from './Konsole';

export type AppProps = ChatProps;

export const App = (props: AppProps, container: HTMLElement) => {
    konsole.log("BotChat.App props", props);
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(AppContainer, props), container);
}

const AppContainer = (props: AppProps) =>
    <div className="wc-app">
        <Chat { ...props } />  //<--------------This is what I want to get
                               //access to on the webpage, which currently
                               //only uses BotChat.App() to initialize the
                               //web chat control. Not sure how to expose
                               //this _instance_ to App.tsx and then expose 
                               //that instance to the webpage.
    </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Chat has a Redux store and a RxJS stream that you can expose to interact with the `<Chat>` component. In React, you can, but people usually don't expose any functions out of it. Short reason: the contract of a React component is props, not functions.

For RxJS stream that you can access the chat history, you can look at the [backchannel sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html). But it's a read-only stream.

For other interactivities, look at [Store.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Store.ts) to see what actions it is using. Then, expose the Redux store at [Chat.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Chat.tsx) (easy hack: thru `window` variable, better: make a callback props at `<Chat>`).

If you need more interactivities that is not in the existing Redux actions, feel free to add some more. For example, this [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/615) should give you a sense of injecting chat history.